# Julia - Broken If statement in while loop?

Tags: debugging, if-statement, while-loop, julia

I am currently trying to constantly check a condition inside an infinite while loop. I am breaking out of the loop with a few conditionals. However, the while loop is immediately breaking and a debugging `println()` shows that the code is inside of the first `if()` statement. Hoover, the preceding line was never run and the if statement needs that information (`polar`) to compute. I only get an error when trying to call polar later in the program and it does not exist. It is as if that line has been entirely skipped.

Here is the while loop in question:

```
prevSize = 0
sec = 0
n = 5
while true # wait unit the polar file is done changing
    polar = readdlm(polarPath,Float64,skipstart = 12)
    if polar[end,1] > aEnd - aStep
        println("Done writing polar file")
        break #File is fully loaded
    else #check every n seconds for stable file size
        sleep(1)
        global sec += 1
        if prevSize == filesize(polarPath) && sec == n
            println("Polar file could not converge for all AoA")
            break # after n seconds if filesize is constant then use current polar
        elseif sec >= n
            global sec = 0 # reset sec every n seconds
        end
        global prevSize = filesize(polarPath)
    end
end
```

The program prints out "Done writing polar file" which means that it used the first `break`. However, `polar` was never initialized as a variable and separately calling `polar[end,1] > aEnd - aStep` gives the expected error of no variable called polar. So my question is how can the code have skipped over the line defining `polar` and then evaluated an if statement that it does not have the information for?

Comment: `polar` is defined inside the while loop so it will live inside the while loop scope.  try to make this into a function and your life will become a lot easier. then you can get rid of all those `global` statements for the rest of the variables too.

Comment: @niczky12 Thanks the global polar fixed the issue. I can see how a function would get rid of the global for polar, but how would that fix the other globals? Or are you suggesting multiple functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how scoping rules work when using a `while` loop.

First example, using `while` inside main:

```
julia> outvar = 5
5

julia> invar = 5
5

julia> while true
           global outvar
           invar = outvar
           outvar += 1
           if outvar > 10
               break
           end
       end

julia> outvar
11

julia> invar
5
```

So I defined both `outvar` and `invar` outside of the while loop, accessed the `outvar` variable outside the scope `while` by calling `global outvar` so the loop works and it does update `outvar`. But our `invar` variable is still set to 5, as the variable `invar` inside the `while` loop is not connected to the outside the `while` loop - it lives in its own tiny universe.

An easy way to fix this is to create a function:

```
function add_nums(outvar)
    invar = outvar
    while true
        invar = outvar 
        outvar += 1
        if outvar > 10
            break
        end
    end
    return invar
end
```

This takes an `outvar`, defines `invar` outside the `while` loop so that you can add additional logic here if you wanted to and the executes the loop and returns your new `invar`.

Once you have this function you can achieve the goal of the original while loop easily:

```
julia> outvar = 5
5

julia> invar = add_nums(outvar)
10
```

Even better, your `outvar` variable is affected by these function calls:

```
julia> outvar
5
```

I hope the above example helps you achieve what you want. You just need to create a function that implements your file loading logic.